# Angular - Parent form not updating, when invalid form is bound to the child form controller which is also an angular component

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a use case where the form object is created in a service, now when the page is showed in a dialog the form is read from the service in the **ngOnInit** and is bound to a local variable which is used in the template. The form is later on used to read the data.

The problem is as follows, when the form is valid and the user navigates to the next page and return to this page everything works fine, BUT when the form is invalid and the user leaves then returns the parent form does not update correctly.

The child component has the correct validity, but the parent form stays invalid.
I noticed that between these 2 use cases the difference is the error object in the forms.

I tried to update the validity by calling **updateValueAndValidity** on the parent form. But it did not work.

The only thing that worked is calling **setValidators([])** on the child form control without any validators. It did not have validators to begin with.

Here is a stackblitz example of the problem.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-app-example-ent7s2?embed=1&file=src/app/parent-form-component/parent-form.component.ts&view=preview

Comment: This will sound rather stupid, but I did not save it correctly. I'm in the process of fixing the example

Comment: Example fixed, now I made sure I saved it!!!!! Also, a few pointers for testing the case through the example when both forms are false. That is invalid. Toggle the forms, when they come back the parent component wont update unless you un comment the line in the ngOnInit in the parent. That is the question. Why is it the way it is. Why doesn't it update it correctly without being 'reset' like that?

Answer (score 2):

I believe I fixed it. The issue was that every time that the ngOnInit was called the original form (in the app-component) was losing the reference of the child FormGroup due to the "new FormGroup()" statement inside the child-component.
To avoid that issue you should try not to reassign the FormGroups inside the form.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! The app-component is the global container its being called only once. My goal was to keep the reference there and when ever the parent-form was re injected into the DOM it would get the same form. Now the problem is with the validators on the form that is being injected and the error. What you are describing is the problem just one level lower :D